# Android just like gallery, how to fling fast to change image fast in single Imageview

Tags: android, image, touch, onfling

My requirement is on touch move I have to change image in image view.If user fling fast based on velocity I want to get fling speed interval and  change image.

I am able to get X and Y velocity, but based on velocity how to find timer interval to apply image change.Please provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This link helps you detect the fling gesture. 
http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

The first and second param of the fling() are **MotionEvent** objects that have a getDownTime() that you can retrieve to get the initial and the final time of the event.([See](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html))

Subtract the same to get the interval.

Comment: I want to make the just like gallery fast fling feature to change image fast .Based on fling speed change image faster .

Comment: Are you doing this thumbnail thing in a gridview?

Comment: No just like gallery, I change images in single image view for giving animation effect on image on touch.I am not using any list.